# Importing Multiple key in the authorized_keys for same host

Tags: networking, encryption, sshd, authorized-keys, pscp

I am setting up a  SSH password less connection setup for two server for the first time. I have imported a public key earlier by vi to authorized_keys, but since this was  failing so i have asked remote Server team ( Windows using PSCP) to generate one more pri/pub key pair & imported the latest key also by appending the new key in the authorized_keys file.
However I have  not  removed the earlier key from the authorized_keys and the SSH is still failing with same error. Could you please tell me if this is the reason for this failure.
Below is the set of logs  generated from the  PSCP  logging  from remote server trying to connect 

Event Log: Writing new session log (SSH packets mode) to file: D:\ssh\ssh.txt

Event Log: Server version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3

Event Log: We believe remote version has SSH-2 channel request bug

Event Log: Using SSH protocol version 2

Outgoing packet #0x0, type 20 / 0x14 (SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT)

Incoming packet #0x0, type 20 / 0x14 (SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT)

Event Log: Doing Diffie-Hellman group exchange

Outgoing packet #0x1, type 34 / 0x22 (SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST)

Incoming packet #0x1, type 31 / 0x1f (SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP)

Event Log: Doing Diffie-Hellman key exchange with hash SHA-256

Outgoing packet #0x2, type 32 / 0x20 (SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT)

Incoming packet #0x2, type 33 / 0x21 (SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY)

Event Log: Host key fingerprint is:

 Outgoing packet #0x3, type 21 / 0x15 (SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS)

Event Log: Initialised AES-128 SDCTR client->server encryption

Event Log: Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 client->server MAC algorithm

Incoming packet #0x3, type 21 / 0x15 (SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS)

Event Log: Initialised AES-128 SDCTR server->client encryption

Event Log: Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 server->client MAC algorithm

Outgoing packet #0x4, type 5 / 0x05 (SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST)

Incoming packet #0x4, type 6 / 0x06 (SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT)

Event Log: Reading private key file "key.ppk"

Outgoing packet #0x5, type 50 / 0x32 (SSH2_MSG_USERAUTH_REQUEST)

Incoming packet #0x5, type 53 / 0x35 (SSH2_MSG_USERAUTH_BANNER)

Incoming packet #0x6, type 51 / 0x33 (SSH2_MSG_USERAUTH_FAILURE)

Outgoing packet #0x6, type 50 / 0x32 (SSH2_MSG_USERAUTH_REQUEST)

Event Log: Offered public key

Incoming packet #0x7, type 60 / 0x3c (SSH2_MSG_USERAUTH_PK_OK)

Event Log: Offer of public key accepted

Outgoing packet #0x7, type 50 / 0x32 (SSH2_MSG_USERAUTH_REQUEST)

Event Log: Sent public key signature

Event Log: Server unexpectedly closed network connection

Below the the logs from the windows server trying to connect to Linux  generated via   -v option of pscp   
                                  C:\Users\User>pscp -i "private.ppk" -P 22 -l User -v -sftp
 "file.txt" server.domain.com:/outboundpath/

Looking up host "server.domain.com"

Connecting to 199.199.199.127 port 22

We claim version: SSH-2.0-PuTTY_Release_0.67

Server version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3

We believe remote version has SSH-2 channel request bug

Using SSH protocol version 2

Doing Diffie-Hellman group exchange

Doing Diffie-Hellman key exchange with hash SHA-256

Host key fingerprint is:

ssh-rsa 2048  

Initialised AES-128 SDCTR client->server encryption

Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 client->server MAC algorithm

Initialised AES-128 SDCTR server->client encryption

Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 server->client MAC algorithm

Reading private key file "private.ppk"

Using username "connect".
                                LEGAL NOTICE

```
      You may commit a criminal offence if you act outside your
               authority in relation to this computer.
```

Offered public key

Offer of public key accepted

Authenticating with public key "rsa-key-20170424"

Sent public key signature

Server unexpectedly closed network connection

Fatal: Server unexpectedly closed network connection

Comment: Usually errors like this are related to public key rejections or permissions errors. Double-check that the server is using the right permissions on `.ssh` and `.authorized_keys` and double-check that the key in the authorized key file doesn't have extraneous spaces or carriage returns.

Comment: Thanks  Patrick.... Could you please tell me if i  already have a public key for same server in authorized keys file ( which i think was incorrect ) , will the adding the another public key  for same server ( Newly generated ) by appending the new key after the old key will result into a issue

Comment: No. The authorized_keys file can contain multiple keys. Make sure when you're pasting in that there are no line breaks in the key, otherwise it will be considered invalid. This applies mainly to Windows editing programs, just double-check that you paste it in as one line. You can also use ssh-copy-id to automate the copying process over to the server. You will have to use password auth temporarily to get this to work.

Comment: Thanks for info.... Could you please tell me how can i mark this as a answer.

Comment: I will post it as an answer so you can mark it.

Answer (score 0):

Usually errors like this are related to public key rejections or permissions errors. Double-check that the server is using the right permissions on `.ssh` and `.authorized_keys` and double-check that the key in the authorized key file doesn't have extraneous spaces or carriage returns.

The authorized_keys file can contain multiple keys. Make sure when you're pasting in that there are no line breaks in the key, otherwise it will be considered invalid. This applies mainly to Windows editing programs, just double-check that you paste it in as one line. You can also use `ssh-copy-id` to automate the copying process over to the server. You will have to use password auth temporarily to get this to work